# Maximum number of categories in Magento CE, and potential performance problems

Tags: magento-1.9, category, performance, magento-community

Is there a magic number, or some guide as to what is a realistic limit for the number of categories a Magento catalog can contain?

A project I'm working on will need to feature some 9000 or so categories - is this an achievable number in Magento Community Edition?

I know there are concerns with large product catalogs, but I can't find any information around large category sets.

Comment: As a heads up, working on a menu system and category collections massively eat time and memory if you don't do proper collection manipulation. They're still quite resource intensive if you do it right.

Comment: @FiascoLabs That's a good point - can you elaborate what you mean by collection manipulation? The majority of the categories required are of a specific type, and these need not form part of the main menu system. (How to go about this is a question in itself).

Comment: Loading collections within foreach loops is one issue that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic number, personally I've built ecomm solutions that have 100s of thousands of products, and 1000 of categories using CE. Long as you have a proper server, caching and optimizations it'll run practically the same as if you only have a handful of products and categories.